# Error trying to access app locally - Heroku and python3

Tags: python, django, heroku

I'm trying to follow the instructions on ["Getting started on Heroku with Python"](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-python#run-the-app-locally), and I've gotten stuck at trying to install "collectstatic". When I try to run the command `python3 manage.py collectstatic`, I get this page of errors:

```
 `Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "manage.py", line 11, in <module>
        execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
      File 
    "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-
    packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 371, in 
    execute_from_command_line
        utility.execute()
      File 
    "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-
    packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 317, in execute
    settings.INSTALLED_APPS
      File 
    "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-
    packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 56, in __getattr__
        self._setup(name)
      File 
    "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-
    packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 43, in _setup
        self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
      File 
    "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-
    packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 106, in __init__
        mod = importlib.import_module(self.SETTINGS_MODULE)
      File 


 "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
        return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 994, in _gcd_import
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 955, in 
    _find_and_load_unlocked
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 665, in _load_unlocked
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 678, in 
    exec_module
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in 
    _call_with_frames_removed
      File "/Users/markdenieffe/python-getting-
    started/gettingstarted/settings.py", line 14, in <module>
        import django_heroku
    ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django_heroku'`
```

This is the first time i've actually used python in a "real world" situation, so I apologise if this is an easy answer, but i've been tearing my hair out for a couple of days over this now.

I've gone to the scripts **init**.py and included `from . import *` to see if the module it needs is in there, but no change.

I've also commented out the line in manage.py that this error `File "manage.py", line 11, in <module>` referred to, but then the program doesn't even attempt to run.

Many thanks for your help.

Comment: did you install `django_heroku`? check if you can import it into your env when opening a shell for example.

Comment: hansTheFranz you genius. For some reason i didn't think django_heroku would be a separate install package...

So now when i try to start the local server with `heroku local`, i get this error...
`Marks-MBP:python-getting-started (user)$ heroku local
[OKAY] Loaded ENV .env File as KEY=VALUE Format
14:41:34 web.1   |  /bin/sh: gunicorn: command not found
14:41:34 web.1   Exited with exit code 127`

Comment: Ok i just had to install gunicorn... Thanks for the help hansTheFranz you the Manz

Comment: we all been there ;)

Comment: This was also my issue. I spent 3 hours resetting my configs and installing and uninstalling stuff until I read this. Thank you!